# How does nginx support cgi?

Tags: nginx, cgi

With apache ,I just put my binary under `cgi-bin`,how about nginx?

Does it support `cgi` at all?

Answer (score 4):

Nginx does not support CGI, because it does not spawn external processes. This is a design decision: Nginx is a high-performance web server and spawning an external process is rather expensive operation.

Comment: why support of cgi means spawn external processes?

Comment: @kernel because there's no way Nginx is going to embed a way to execute cgi.

Comment: why can't nginx use the same way as executing PHP to execute cgi?

Comment: @kernel CGI (Common Gateway Interface) implies a script is executed by an HTTP server (RFC 3875, section 3.4: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875.txt). Apache may execute a PHP script as CGI or using "mod_php" module (which is not CGI obviously)

Answer (score 0):

It does support FastCGI and UWSGI, though.